# Find top N game for every ID based on total time using spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Find top N Game for every `id` who watched based on total time so here is my input dataframe:

**InputDF**:

```
id    |    Game  |  Time
 1           A       10
 2           B       100
 1           A       100
 2           C       105
 1           N       103
 2           B       102
 1           N       90
 2           C       110
```

And this is the output that I am expecting:

**OutputDF:**

```
id    |  Game   |  Time|
 1          N       193
 1          A       110
 2          C       215
 2          B       202
```

Here what I have tried but it is not working as expected:

```
val windowDF = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"Time".desc)
   
   InputDF.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(windowDF))
      .filter("rank<=10")
```

Comment: The `OutputDF` looks like the result of a `groupBy('id, 'Game).sum('Time)`. What exactly do you mean when you say "Find topN ... based on total time"? Should only the top N of each group be summed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top-N ranking applies only to individual `time` rather than `total time` per game.  A `groupBy/sum` to compute `total time` followed by a ranking on the `total time` will do:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "A", 10),
  (2, "B", 100),
  (1, "A", 100),
  (2, "C", 105),
  (1, "N", 103),
  (2, "B", 102),
  (1, "N", 90),
  (2, "C", 110)
).toDF("id", "game", "time")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val win = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"total_time".desc)

df.
  groupBy("id", "game").agg(sum("time").as("total_time")).
  withColumn("rank", row_number.over(win)).
  where($"rank" <= 10).
  show
// +---+----+----------+----+
// | id|game|total_time|rank|
// +---+----+----------+----+
// |  1|   N|       193|   1|
// |  1|   A|       110|   2|
// |  2|   C|       215|   1|
// |  2|   B|       202|   2|
// +---+----+----------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also solved it with kind of similar query.